# Загрузочное окружение Windows: Legacy или UEFI?

Tags: winapi, windows-10, powershell, wmi, bios

Долгие поиски в сети не дали результата, поэтому обращаюсь за помощью к знатокам. Возможно ли в Windows получить загрузочное окружение, в смысле, *Legacy* или *UEFI*? Я полагала, что эту информацию можно выудить из *WMI* класса ***Win32_BIOS***, но, как оказалось, я ошибалась. Возможно, есть какие-то другие классы, о которых мне неизвестно, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует ли нечто подобное в WMI не в курсе, но если задуматься над использованием WinAPI, точнее NTAPI, можно обратиться к **NtQuerySystemInformation** для получения поля *FirmwareType* структуры с весьма красноречивым названием - **SYSTEM_BOOT_ENVIRONMENT_INFORMATION**. Данная структура имеет вид:

```
   +0x000 BootIdentifier   : _GUID
   +0x010 FirmwareType     : _FIRMWARE_TYPE
   +0x018 BootFlags        : Uint8B
   +0x018 DbgMenuOsSelection : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x018 DbgHiberBoot     : Pos 1, 1 Bit
   +0x018 DbgSoftBoot      : Pos 2, 1 Bit
   +0x018 DbgMeasuredLaunch : Pos 3, 1 Bit
```

Размер структуры в 32- и 64-битных системах одинаков и равен тридцати двум байтам, правда, если память не изменяет, структура была введена (если так можно выразиться лексически) с Windows Vista. Прочитать структуру в PowerShell можно, например, так:

```
using namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices

try {
  $ptr = [Marshal]::AllocHGlobal(32)
  if ([Regex].Assembly.GetType(
    'Microsoft.Win32.NativeMethods'
  ).GetMethod('NtQuerySystemInformation').Invoke(
    $null, @(90, $ptr, 32, $null)
  ) -ne 0) { throw }

  $guid = (0..15).ForEach{[Marshal]::ReadByte($ptr, $_)}
  $guid = "{$((([BitConverter]::ToUInt32($guid[0..3], 0),
    [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($guid[4..5], 0),
  [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($guid[6..7], 0)).ForEach{$_.ToString('X')}) +
  -join($b = $guid[8..16].ForEach{$_.ToString('X2')})[0..1],
  -join($b[2..7]) -join '-')}"

  $type = ('Unknown', 'BIOS', 'UEFI', 'Max')[[Marshal]::ReadInt64($ptr, 16)]

  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    BootIdentifier = $guid
    FirmwareType = $type
  }
}
catch { $_ }
finally {
  if ($ptr) { [Marshal]::FreeHGlobal($ptr) }
}
```

**Дополненние**
Начиная с Windows 8, определить загрузочное окружение можно либо с помощью WinAPI функции [GetFirmwareType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfirmwaretype), либо запросив данные недокументированной переменной **%FIRMWARE_TYPE%**.

```
Get-Content env:firmware_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Мой ответ будет не полным, тем более, что правильный уже дан, но будет касаться использования именно WMI:

Структура Win32_BIOS по умолчанию не содержит данных, в каком режиме загружена ОС, однако некоторые производители материнских плат, видимо, дают расширенную информацию. Но установить точно даже для мат. плат от Intel (они обычно славятся подобным функционалом) мне не удалось: на каких-то получалось, на каких-то нет.

Но можно взглянуть на проблему с другой стороны: запросить данные о таблице разделов на жестком диске. В случае, если **системный диск** имеет GPT, а не MBR, то, если у нас установлена 64-битная Windows 7, 8 или 10, мы однозначно грузились в UEFI-режиме. В случае 32-битной ОС это не 100%-но, но очень вероятно.

А получить эту информацию можно через класс `Win32_DiskPartition`, запрашивая объекты с типом `"GPT: System"`, например, так:

```
Get-WmiObject  -query 'Select * from Win32_DiskPartition Where Type = "GPT: System"'
```